# Track analytics on dropbox file downloads

Tags: php, google-analytics, mp3

I'm running a podcast.  The audio plays on my blog, and is available for download.  I can track analytics on that very easily.  Currently, I'm also hosting the mp3 on my own server so tracking access to the mp3 itself is also easy, but with almost 1000 downloads/listens on the first episode, the bandwidth is quite high.  I'd like to offload the files to an external cloud service, but I don't know how to track plays. iTunes uses an XML feed that I provide indicating things like file location, title, description, etc.  They do NOT track usage data or even number of subscribers for you.

So my issue is, how do I track the analytics on the mp3 plays/downloads of a file hosted in the cloud (dropbox/drive/amazon/etc)? I've thought about trying a method like timthumb where the url is to a php file with a few url variables, and the serverside script hits analytics, and then serves up the mp3 using HTTP headers.  I just don't know if that would work and the only way to test it is to actually try it on the live podcast - frightening.

Any thoughts to point me in the right direction? I've scoured the googles but have come up empty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this out.  Here's how:

In my .htaccess file, I look for the mp3 file request:

`RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.mp3$ audio.php/?file=$1.mp3 [QSA,L,R=301]`

In my audio.php file, I use Server Side Google Analytics thanks to dancameron (https://github.com/dancameron/server-side-google-analytics):

```
//Grab the file name
$file = $_GET['file'];

//create new ssga object
include('/home/flightca/public_html/wp-content/themes/flightcast/lib/ss-ga.class.php');
$ssga = new ssga( 'UA-XXXXXXXX-0', 'WEBSITE.URL' );

//send to analytics as an event
$ssga->set_event( 'Audio', 'Plays', $file, $file );
$ssga->send();
```

Finally, in my audio.php file I redirect the user to the file in the cloud:

```
//send user to audio file in the cloud
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: https://preferred-cnd-of-choice.com/audio/".$file);
```